# Turing Machine question, this is NOT HW

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, turing-machines

I was having a hard time understanding and solving this question that wants me to show the final tape and figuring out if whether or not the turning machine accepts it or not. I have a list of 20 problems, that I want to solve to prepare for my interview at Mathworks, and the if any of you can help me solve these 2, I will solve the remaining on my own. An explanation would help.

Does the TM accept

A)101010
B)00100
The turing machine is here,

[image]

And to design a turing machine that accepts {a^2n : n>0}

I appreciate your help, I really want to learn it, and I learn by examples, thanks.

Thank you

Comment: 1)  without seeing the TM, nobody can answer.  2) I count two problems, not three.

Comment: @RossMillikan I apologize, fixed it now and added the image. Please help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @RossMillikan is it fine now?

Comment: Would the notation $10R$ mean "when you read a $1$ write a $0$ on the tape and move the head right"?  And does $\Delta$ denote the blank symbol?

Comment: @ArthurFischer yes.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Just verified, that's right.